# Android 6 Exception (google map?)

Tags: android

I get exception in firebase crash report.

But don`t understand cause of exception.

App work on android 5 good

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'java.lang.Object ade.a(int, 
java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' is inaccessible to class 
'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fb' (declaration of 
'com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fb' appears in 
/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/
00000013/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fb.run 
(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:5259)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker 
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

I use last libs

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
```

P.S. Change libs using to

```
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
```

P.S.S

Work on Android 5 device, Android emulator 6.0, Android emulator 7.0

Crash on Android 6.0.1 device

Which cause can be?

Comment: Were you able to find the cause of the crash?

Comment: @usman I not work with this project now. Last what i changed in a project - disable minification.

Comment: Ok. so u mean u can overcome the above crash by disabling minification?

Comment: Are you using proguard ?

Comment: I've seen similar crashes on rooted devices. I'm still not sure what causes it but with a rooted device it could be anything..

Answer (score 1):

@Alexandr. It would be great if you post the list of installed libraries from gradle file.

I too suffered similar problem before. We should first remember that, try not to use different `versions` between `firebase libraries` and `google play services`. They both should have same version number.

Since you used `10.2.4` version for google play service, same version should be used for firebase libraries too. Using cross-version sometimes creates a run-time problem and is also warned in android-studio to avoid it.

But this also sometimes does not work and didn't solve my problem then. So changed `10.2.4` to latest version `11.x.x` and it solved. If it didn't again, try another version but near to the latest one.

Here is the link to the [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and [google-play-service](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) latest library list. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be because of the library.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
```

If your are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
```

you don't have to use `play-services-maps:10.2.4` once again.

So, I would suggest you to use only the library dependency that actually your project wants. As full version of `play-services` library may lead to *65K* method error as described in [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) of Google Play Services Library Setup.

And to understand the Firebase crash report you have to upload `mapping.txt` file to your Firebase console. For more refer this [Firebase Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android)

Comment: Change to     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4' - no results, Exception java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Comment: Make sure that the Google Play Services version is upto date on Android 6.0.1 device.

Comment: installed last version (10.2.98) same as on android 5

Comment: Did you try debug on Android 6.0.1 device?

Comment: I have not device with 6.0.1 have only log http://clip2net.com/s/3K2KTpv